# Question about Study in Scarlet TWO

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'd like to ask about following sentences from Study in Scarlet by Conan Doyle.

> A higher Judge had taken the matter in hand, and Jefferson Hope had been summoned before a tribunal where strict justice would be meted out to him.

For me, the above sentence seems ambiguous.

A: Hope had been summoned before(in front of) a tribunal where～ 
So Hope is sent in front of an upper tribunal where god handles matter.

B: Hope had been summoned(to the god), before a tribunal where～
So Hope is sent to the god, before mortal's tribunal where human judges handle matter.

Can this sentence be ambiguous or it has only one possibility for English speakers?  Thank you.

Comment: I see no ambiguity, only an assumption: **Jefferson Hope had been summoned [to appear] before a tribunal.**

Comment: There is no ambiguity.  The _higher Judge_ is indeed god and when Doyle says he was _summoned before a tribunal_, he means that Hope died.  _Gone to meet his maker_ is a common euphemism for death and that's what has happened here.  Hope died before he could be tried on earth and would be judged by god.

Comment: Also, I will note that this is the second question you've posted without taking [the site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out what this site is about.  You might also want to explore the help center where you'll find topics such as [how to ask a good question](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @RogerSinasohn perhaps you had already read the book, or recently skimmed it. Your first comment is worthy.

Comment: @WeatherVane -- I had written a long answer which started out saying that there's no god involved here, but then I did a google search to get a little more context and, after reading that passage, discovered that, yes, the Judge is god (hence the capital J) and Hope indeed died.  So I can't really take a lot of credit for being well read or knowledgeable or anything.  But I am reminded of the scene in _National Treasure_ where the bad guy ponders why the S in Silence is capitalized.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn because it is someone's (pen) name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81298/discussion-between-roger-sinasohn-and-weather-vane).

Comment: And it's a common euphemism too eh?  Thanks.

Comment: It's a metaphor. But literal or not, it's not ambiguous as far as who does what to whom. So A is the right understanding of the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important point here is the capital letter for 'Judge'. Mr Justice Smith, of the English High Court, is a judge: he is not "a higher Judge", which title is reserved for One judge alone.

(This question seems to me good enough for ELU, because of the point you did not pick up on; but general questions about normal English need both some research by you and consideration whether they should be asked here or on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).)

Comment: The capital J, that's I am oblivious about. So this isn't ambiguous at all. Thank you.

Comment: Yes; in English writing, an unexpected capital letter on any word for an entity (God, Him, He, You, Judge, Maker, etc.) usually means that God (a specific, singular god like the Christian God, Jehovah, or Allah) is being referred to.